# Confused with binary to hex ARM encoding

Tags: assembly, arm, machine-code, opcode

Can you explain to me, please, why the heck is there 16 instructions in the following example? I thought there were more. And how the heck can I translate this binary scheme into HEX string?
Let's, for example, take the following: `0000 00 1 1101 0 0000 0001 000000000101`.
Can you explain, please, what is **shift** in case of **imm** and **reg**.

And, please, whether it's enough to convert the **binary** from example to **HEX** (`3A01005`) and simply use it as an encoding for ARM instruction? Because several online disassemblers returns an *"Invalid opcode"*.

Best regards, *Assembler's Newbie* :D
[image: Arm instruction encoding]

Comment: `.inst 0x3A01005` assembles + disassembles into `03a01005        moveq   r1, #5` for me, in ARM mode with `arm-none-eabi-gcc -c` and `arm-none-eabi-objdump`; yeah, your translation to hex of that bit-pattern is correct.

Comment: @PeterCordes that's strange. Plus, you are using .inst directive. I thought it would work like pasting just HEX code into "regular file" (I mean file of type .o or smth)

Comment: @PeterCordes as well as ARM64 disassembler shows this - adr x26, #0x26 (https://disasm.pro/)

Comment: Perhaps this is an endianness mismatch? What happens if you try to disassemble `0510A003`?

Comment: this is not the complete documentation for the instruction set, when you read the rest of and newer or other versions of the documentation, please explain what part you did not understand.

Comment: newer, current, versions of binutils you can use .inst in gnu assembly language to type in the instruction in machine code form (hex code as you are calling it). older versions of gnu assembler you would use .word instead. (try .inst if it complains try .word)

Comment: how did you assemble it in order to have a disassembler report invalid opcode?

Comment: *what is shift in case of imm and reg.* - shift is a shift. A value is shifted bitwise by a specified number of bits before an operation is performed. You must know what shift is if you plan to learn assembly. Do you know C? '<<' and '>>' operations in C?

Comment: Note that ARM64 has an entirely differen instruction encoding and is not comparable.  Also make sure to disassemble in ARM, not Thumb mode.

Comment: @TonyK same happens)

Comment: @old_timer i'm trying to use online disassemblers for now. Like disasm.pro etc.

Comment: @tum_ I know about bitwise shifting, but wasn't sure it's doing same in ARM

Comment: @fuz ahh, I see. Thanks

Comment: It works fine [here](http://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/?opcodes=03+A0+10+05&arch=arm&endianness=big&dis_with_addr=True&dis_with_raw=True&dis_with_ins=True#disassembly). (But you have to specify the bytes separately.)

Comment: `.o` files hold *binary* machine code, not ASCII hex dumps of it.  You obviously can't `echo 03A01005 >> foo.o`, for that reason and the fact that `.o` files have metadata for sections, not flat binaries where you can just tack on more bytes.  You could use a hex editor to change the bytes of an instruction in a .o to match the bytes represented by `03A01005`

Comment: cant disassemble until you assemble. and the assembly language is specific to the assembler (not the target).  how are you creating the object to disassemble online?  I would use easy to use and well known tools like gnu first.

Comment: and not all disassemblers are accurate, would argue that none are.  if you are trying to disassemble then perhaps provide more of the data you are trying to disassemble.  for example is the tool trying to disassemble data ?

Comment: is this purely 32 bit arm or are there thumb instructions mixed in too (odds of the disassembler working go down dramatically, odds of errors go up dramatically)

Comment: what are you disassembling, how did you create it can, you provide a repeatable example?

Comment: @TonyK awww, I see now) Thanks a lot ;) 'll continue to learn

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, dude ;) I'll dive inside this topic

Comment: @old_timer I'm kinda new to all this stuff, especially for ARM. I was trying to understand Intel x86_64 instruction encoding, using nasm and it's -l command modifier. It works for me fine. Then I've turned for ARM and from the first glance there was some misunderstanding with manuals. Though, I partially understand it's assembly language for now

Comment: the arm manuals are significantly better than the x86 manuals.  certainly with respect to instruction encoding.  Based on the picture you provided you need to go get the actual arm reference manual(s), start with the armv5 architectural reference manual.  no confusion.  demonstration of what a good document looks like.

Comment: @old_timer thanks a lot) this is my actual step for now <3

Comment: @old_timer: Some online disassemblers let you paste raw hex (of machine code bytes), so no you don't have to assemble first.  e.g. http://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/?opcodes=03+A0+10+05&arch=arm&endianness=big&dis_with_addr=True&dis_with_raw=True&dis_with_ins=True#disassembly  (I'm not sure exactly what the big/little endian radio buttons do in disassemble.  Apparently one of them munges your byte-stream even if you separate each pair of hex digits, probably intended for word-at-a-time hex dumps of binary data encountered in the wild.)